# how can I ask another questions in my code after choosing one of the options?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, prompt

Hello I have a problem with this exercise:
Write a program that calculates the area of a figure?

What figure? 1 - rectangle, 2 - triangle
if user will choose rectangle the program should ask questions:
-Enter base length:
-Enter the height of the rectangle:
statement: This field is:

if user will choose second options what is triangle a program will ask questions as:
-Enter the side length
-Enter the length of side
statement: The area of the triangle is:

```
    var bok1 = Number(prompt("Ile wynosi pierwszy bok prostokata?"));
    var bok2 = Number(prompt("Ile wynosi drugi bok prostokata?"));
    var podstawa trojkata = Number(prompt("Podaj długość podstawy:"));
    var wysokosc trojkata = Number(prompt("Podaj wysokosc podstawy:"));
    var co_obliczyc = (prompt("Co chcesz obliczyc? prostokat czy trojkat?"));
    switch(co_obliczyc) {
```

so I wrote sth like that and stuck I don't want my program to ask every questions at first and then calculate I want program to ask about the figure then if user will chose one of this he has to give dimensions for the selected figure I have no idea how to do this please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just swap the order of questions:

```js
var co_obliczyc = (prompt("Co chcesz obliczyc? prostokat czy trojkat?"));
switch(co_obliczyc) {
   case "prostokat":
      var bok1 = Number(prompt("Ile wynosi pierwszy bok prostokata?"));
      var bok2 = Number(prompt("Ile wynosi drugi bok prostokata?"));
      //logic for rectangle
      break;
   case "trojkat":
      var podstawa_trojkata = Number(prompt("Podaj długość podstawy:"));
      var wysokosc_trojkata = Number(prompt("Podaj wysokosc podstawy:"));
      //logic for triangle
      break;
   default:
      alert("Not implemented")//Sorry, I don't know how to write it in Polish
      break;
}
```